# DSpace 7 - Creating custom fields on edit metadata page

Tags: angular, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend, dspace

I'm having a hard time trying to learn Angular and DSpace 7 at the same time while being a new student to both of them.
The challenge i'm currently facing is that i must create a new field on edit metadata page that has 3 input fields grouped together that can be repeatable and "deletable" as a group too.
These fields are:

1. A simple input text field.
2. A date picker field.
3. A dropdown list.

My back-end guys told me that DSpace already "knows" these input types as "onebox", "date" and "dropdown" in the XML they provided from the back-end.
Now the thing is that i'm so new to all of these that i don't even know how to approach this task.
Should i use those exact types and nest them under a new "father" component that will be in charge of the repeatable/deletable functionality?
Should i replicate clones of these types for example "custom-onebox" etc, and work with them?
Should i ignore all cases above and create new components from scratch with Angular?

I managed via the XML and using its  and  tags to bring these 3 fields in one line on the UI but of course that's not much.
I tried creating new clone components with Angular but there are soooo many imports and cross communications between components that a simple copy-paste and proper renaming haven't done me any favors.

Thank you all for your time in advance!